# Where I can get index css

Tags: html, css

Sometimes browser shows `index css` like in screenshot below:

[image]

I am making `font-family: !important` in my *style.css* file but as you can see `!important`  already given in index file.

How can I override the css or can I get this index css from somewhere?

Comment: Probably PHP generated CSS file....

Comment: You could place your `custom.css` stylesheet beneath the `index.css` stylesheet to avoid this.

Comment: I think that is the z-index or y-index of css class?

Comment: I don't think it's a stylesheet, as in an external `.css` file, but the style tag directly added into the page.

Comment: As this index says "49", does the next say "50" (in level with media="") ?

Comment: ... and if it does say "50", it's for sure the index number for that particular css class within the style sheet

Comment: How can i put this code beneath the `index.css` cos i am not geting the exact file @Siyah.

Comment: If you view source on the page, do you see the CSS in-between `<style>` tags?

Comment: that will we inner style sheet in you template

Comment: Yes Nick You are right, so where i can get it ?

Comment: Is that code coming from google `fonts` .?

Comment: I assume this is a Wordpress site? Either way, something is adding the CSS to the page. It's probably worth doing a `file in files` search with something like `Notepad++`, so you can see where it's adding those styles.